# Add flags under HTTP response header

Tags: http, header, response

I have a web based application that runs on JBoss 4.2.1. I want to add **secure** and **http only** flags under **SET-COOKIE** response header. I have written a filter in java using OWASP's ESAPI library to do that. Following is the java code for the same.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    SecurityWrapperResponse securityWrapperResponse = new SecurityWrapperResponse(httpServletResponse);

    Cookie[] cookies = httpServletRequest.getCookies();
    if (cookies != null) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) 
        {
            Cookie cookie = cookies[i];
            if (cookie != null) 
            {
             securityWrapperResponse.addCookie(cookie);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When I start the server and load a page, these attributes do not appear under response header. But once I refresh the page I am able to see all of it. What could be the problem here that stops populating these flags under response header when the page loads for the first time ?

Please provide your inputs here...

Thanks